# Odoo server times-out, and memory limit

Tags: php, python, odoo

I'm uploading a very large file on Odoo, but it times out.

I want to ask what is alternative to PHP's `php.ini` file in Odoo. Like in `php.ini`, we can change the server time out, memory limit and other configurations. How can I do the same in Odoo? I've made changes in `openerp-wsgi.py` but they're not reflected.

Comment: How big is the file you are trying to upload?

Comment: It's 130 MB, about 400,000 records

Answer (score 2):

It is `/etc/odoo/openerp-server.conf` by default in Ubuntu.
See explanation of config at http://www.vionblog.com/openerp-server-conf-for-openerp-7-explained/